# Insert into Oracle SQL or Update if value already exist?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

What I want is:  `If key exist in Oracle SQL Table → UPDATE, otherwise do a INSERT`

After playing all day yesterday, I managed to get the INSERT part (query below), what I now need is the UPDATE part.

This is why I need it: I have a RadGridView (using Telerik and WPF). When a User clicks on Insert button a new Row is added and after the User hits Enter, the value is Inserted into the Database. But the user can also click on a available row in the RadGridView and update the values, so I need to update the values in my Database too (and not do a INSERT). And that is why I want a query that can perform a Udate or Insert.

Any help is appreciated, also if you have a better way of implementing the INSERT part, I would like to know about it  :)

I am using Oracle SQL Developer (Windows 10).

**ps.** I tried some solutions I found on StackOverflow but could not manage to apply the solutions to my problem.

**Table1**

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               ID                  |  ORIGTERM  |  CODE  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| 126478                            | Grass      |  TEST  |
| 374628                            | Flower     |  TEST  |
| 128754                            | Tree       |  TEST  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

**Table2**

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+---------+
|               ID                  |REPLACETERM |SYSCTLANG|
+-----------------------------------+------------+---------+
| 126478                            | Gras       |     3   |
| 374628                            | Blume      |     3   |
| 128754                            | Baum       |     3   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

I managed to got the **INSERT** query, it looks like this (example insert the word 'Plant'):

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO Table1(origterm,code) VALUES (s_origterm,s_code) 
   INTO Table2(replaceterm) VALUES (s_replaceterm) 
  SELECT s_origterm, s_code, s_replaceterm 
    FROM (SELECT 'Plant' s_origterm, 'TEST' s_code, 'Pflanze' s_replaceterm FROM dual) 
    dual;
```

I must also **update the ID of Table2** to be the same as the one from Table1:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET Table2.ID = (SELECT Table1.ID FROM Table1 WHERE origterm='Plant') 
              WHERE replaceterm='Pflanze';
```

Now I have a table that looks like this:

```
    +-----------------------------------+------------+--------------+------+
    |               ID                  |  ORIGTERM  |  REPLACETERM | CODE |
    +-----------------------------------+------------+--------------+------+
    | 126478                            | Grass      |  Gras        | TEST |
    | 374628                            | Flower     |  Blume       | TEST |
    | 128754                            | Tree       |  Baum        | TEST |
    | 100000                            | Plant      |  Pflanze     | TEST |
    +-----------------------------------+------------+--------------+------+
```

> `SELECT g.ID, origterm, replaceterm, code FROM Table1 g, Table2 ct WHERE g.ID = ct.ID;`

Comment: What about using `MERGE` statement?

Comment: @psur Could you show me how please ? How can I apply it to my problem ?

Comment: Why these two tables: table1  & table2 are divided ? Is `ID` column a primary key in one of these two tables ? Why do you use such a data model ? And what is a third table `(ID, ORIGTERM, REPLACETERM, CODE)` -  `table3` ? How do you obtain `id`=100000 value ? Does it come from a sequence or so ? Please explain which table do you need to update, and where the new data come from, because I get lost.

Comment: @kordirko Table1 holds the terms which are not translated and Table2 holds the translated terms. The data model as such is given to me. The third Table is a combination of Table1 and Table2 (look at the hidden SQL query at the end). The ID  is a primary key. When I insert a ORIGTERM Value in the TABLE1 the ID will be set automatically for me,in other words I don't need to add the ID.  I need to update the third Table, but that is done through Table1 and Table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge does not work with INSERT ALL. If you want to use merge, you should make from both table a [view with instead of trigger](http://psoug.org/reference/instead_of_trigger.html) and than use merge against the view. The whole logic will  be inside the trigger.

EDIT: Merge does not work with such views
ORA-38106: MERGE bei Join View oder View mit INSTEAD OF-Trigger nicht unterstützt

You can make two merge statements (one for every table) or one for insert and one for update against view:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MYDICT_SEQ START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 0;

CREATE VIEW mydict
AS
   SELECT a.id, a.origterm, a.code, b.replaceterm, b.sysctlang
     FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id;   

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mydict_io
   INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON mydict
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   cnt1   INTEGER := 0;
   cnt2   INTEGER;
   nid    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
      IF :new.id IS NULL AND INSERTING THEN
         nid := mydict_seq.NEXTVAL;
      ELSE
         nid := :new.id;

         IF UPDATING THEN
            nid := :old.id;
         END IF;

         SELECT COUNT (*)
           INTO cnt1
           FROM table1
          WHERE id = nid;
      END IF;

      IF cnt1 = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, ORIGTERM, CODE)
              VALUES (nID, :new.ORIGTERM, :new.CODE);
      ELSIF cnt1 > 0 THEN
         UPDATE TABLE1
            SET ORIGTERM = :NEW.ORIGTERM, CODE = :NEW.CODE
          WHERE id = nid;
      END IF;

      SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO cnt2
        FROM table2
       WHERE id = nid AND SYSCTLANG = :new.SYSCTLANG;

      IF cnt2 = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, REPLACETERM, SYSCTLANG)
              VALUES (nID, :new.REPLACETERM, :new.SYSCTLANG);
      ELSE
         UPDATE TABLE2
            SET REPLACETERM = :new.REPLACETERM
          WHERE id = nid AND SYSCTLANG = :new.SYSCTLANG;
      END IF;
   ELSIF DELETING THEN
      DELETE FROM table2
            WHERE id = :old.id AND SYSCTLANG = :old.SYSCTLANG;

      SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO cnt2
        FROM table2
       WHERE id = nid;

      IF cnt2 = 0 THEN
         DELETE FROM table1
               WHERE id = :old.id;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;

DECLARE
   nid   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO mydict (ORIGTERM, CODE, REPLACETERM, SYSCTLANG)
        VALUES ('Plant', 'TEST', 'Pflanze', 3);
    nid := mydict_seq.currval;


   UPDATE mydict
      SET REPLACETERM = 'Fabrik'
    WHERE id = nid;

   UPDATE mydict
      SET REPLACETERM = 'Usine', SYSCTLANG = 4
    WHERE id = nid;
END;
```

The logic in the instead of trigger can be done better, but I leave this to you ;)

Comment: WoW, I will have to test this, but it is so big. Was hoping for something smaller. Anyway I will test it and will come back to report.

Comment: @Devid The advantage of the view is that you can bind it direct to RadGridView as DataTable and do not care about insert, delete, update statements

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too obvious but if you own the 'key' value probably this procedure will work:

```
DECLARE _flag AS INT = 0;

SELECT COUNT() INTO _flag FROM table1 WHERE ID = key;

IF _flag = 0 THEN
   INSERT ...
ELSE
   UPDATE ....
END IF;
```

adjust it to your own code needs and/or ORACLE SQL dialect.

Comment: I am not that advanced with SQL, could you please explain a bit your code ? What does DECLARE _flag AS INT = 0; do ?

Comment: declare a variable _flag of type INT and default value 0... the correct syntax may change between SQL dialects but I'm pretty sure it should works.. if you prefer you can split this in two lines.... 
     DECLARE _flag AS INT;
     SET _flag = 0;

Comment: in some SQL dialect you can omit 'AS'

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use the MERGE keyword, documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm

Merge is basically an 'upsert' command, meaning that it will update row if exists or insert, if it doesn't.

Comment: I saw MERGE command, but the problem is when I want to apply it to my problem I am always getting errors. I am making some mistakes. If you could show me how to apply Merge to my Problem I would mark your answer as the Solution  :)